# Elasticsearch does not index on time in Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, jasmine

I have currently a test suite for my elasticsearch api but it seems that all of the tests run before the results are indexed, what I currently have is.

```
  const index = `test-${Math.floor(Math.random())}`;
  const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: "localhost:9200",
    log: "trace",
  });
  const body = {...}
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await client.bulk({ body });
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await client.indices.delete({
      index,
    });
  });
```

I have used async and await in the past but they do not seem to be working now. How can I make sure that the bulk command runs before the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh the index after inserting document(s). There is a delay of 1s before an inserted document becomes searchable. Read about `refresh_interval` setting in Elasticsearch documentation and `/_refresh` endooint.

Comment: I saw there is a way to pass a refresh argument on the parameters of bulk, but the syntax on the elasticsearch api isn't very clear, would you happen to know how to add refresh: true to a bulk request?

Comment: Usually I just make a call to `/_refresh` after the (bulk) insert.

Comment: You might want to read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docs-bulk.html#bulk-refresh

Comment: a call to client.indices.refresh did it. Thanks!